# Neural network for multi label classification with large number of classes outputs only zero

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, keras

I am training a neural network for multilabel classification, with a large number of classes (1000). Which means more than one output can be active for every input. On an average, I have two classes active per output frame. On training with a cross entropy loss the neural network resorts to outputting only zeros, because it gets the least loss with this output since 99.8% of my labels are zeros. Any suggestions on how I can push the network to give more weight to the positive classes?

Answer (score 9):

Tensorflow has a loss function `weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`, which can be used to give more weight to the 1's. So it should be applicable to a sparse multi-label classification setting like yours.

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits):

> This is like sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits() except that pos_weight, allows one to trade off recall and precision by up- or down-weighting the cost of a positive error relative to a negative error.
>
> The argument pos_weight is used as a multiplier for the positive targets

If you use the tensorflow backend in Keras, you can use the loss function like this (Keras 2.1.1):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as tfb

POS_WEIGHT = 10  # multiplier for positive targets, needs to be tuned

def weighted_binary_crossentropy(target, output):
    """
    Weighted binary crossentropy between an output tensor 
    and a target tensor. POS_WEIGHT is used as a multiplier 
    for the positive targets.

    Combination of the following functions:
    * keras.losses.binary_crossentropy
    * keras.backend.tensorflow_backend.binary_crossentropy
    * tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits
    """
    # transform back to logits
    _epsilon = tfb._to_tensor(tfb.epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
    output = tf.clip_by_value(output, _epsilon, 1 - _epsilon)
    output = tf.log(output / (1 - output))
    # compute weighted loss
    loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(targets=target,
                                                    logits=output,
                                                    pos_weight=POS_WEIGHT)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=-1)
```

Then in your model:

```
model.compile(loss=weighted_binary_crossentropy, ...)
```

I have not found many resources yet which report well working values for the `pos_weight` in relation to the number of classes, average active classes, etc.

Comment: Is there a corresponding `weighted_binary_accuracy` metric that can be used for the model as well? (Otherwise the `binary_accuracy` will be biased to the negative predictions as well).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to [tobigue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979377/tobigue) for the great solution.

The tensorflow and keras apis have changed since that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47313183/3182448). So the updated version of `weighted_binary_crossentropy` is below for Tensorflow 2.7.0.

```
import tensorflow as tf

POS_WEIGHT = 10

def weighted_binary_crossentropy(target, output):
    """
    Weighted binary crossentropy between an output tensor 
    and a target tensor. POS_WEIGHT is used as a multiplier 
    for the positive targets.

    Combination of the following functions:
    * keras.losses.binary_crossentropy
    * keras.backend.tensorflow_backend.binary_crossentropy
    * tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits
    """
    # transform back to logits
    _epsilon = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.keras.backend.epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
    output = tf.clip_by_value(output, _epsilon, 1 - _epsilon)
    output = tf.math.log(output / (1 - output))
    loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output, pos_weight=POS_WEIGHT)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=-1)
```